# Xamarin Forms - Binding Multiple TextCells in one ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding, xamarin

I am having trouble binding multiple TextCells in a ListView. It works fine if there's only one, but gives XamlParseException on adding more. The same Exception occurs while trying to bind a Label. That's why I had to use a TextCell. What's the solution?

```
<ListView x:Name="pList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell x:Name="a" Text="{Binding ReceiverName}" TextColor="White" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 4):

From your comment on one of the answers, it looks like this is what you want

```
    <ListView x:Name="pList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout>
                  <Label Text="{Binding ReceiverName}" TextColor="White" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding SecondText}" TextColor="White" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding ThirdText}" TextColor="White" />
                </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell.View>          
             </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This will display 3 Labels vertically.The problem you were having is that the DataTemplate can't have more than one child. The standard way around that is to use a layout control such as StackLayout.

Please see this page for more information: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/layouts/

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the code you've pasted I'd say that the problem is that you give the control a name. Remove the `a:Name` and try again.

If that doesn't help, post the exception details as well.

Comment: Removing the Name attribute did not make any difference.

Got this exception when trying to add another TextCell just below the first one - An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

My problem is not with the given code, it arises when I add another TextCell just beneath the first one.

Comment: Ahh, yes - you need to add the textcells in a view. try surrounding your two cells with a `<StackLayout />`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the "ViewCell" inside the data template like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="pList">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <TextCell x:Name="a" Text="{Binding ReceiverName}" TextColor="White" />
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Actuall what I want to do is - 
<ListView x:Name="pList">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <TextCell x:Name="a" Text="{Binding ReceiverName}" TextColor="White" />
<TextCell x:Name="b" Text="{Binding Address}" TextColor="White" />
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

Answer (score 0):

TextCell also has a detail attribute :

```
<TextCell x:Name="a" Text="{Binding ReceiverName}" Detail="{Binding AnotherName}" TextColor="White" />
```