# Can't display two TextCell

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to display two `TextCell` in `ListView` component. May `MainPage.xaml` code:

```
<StackLayout>

    <Button Text="Go To Map Page" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>

    <ListView x:Name="MyList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Age}" />
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

cs code:

```
namespace App20
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyList.ItemsSource = new List<Person>
            {
               new Person()
               {
                   Name = "Dima",
                   Age = 20
               },
               new Person()
               {
                   Name = "Roma",
                   Age = 21
               },
               new Person()
               {
                   Name = "Masha",
                   Age = 19
               }


            };
        }

        private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MapPage());
        }
    }
}
```

If I am displaying only one of elements (Name or age) all works fine. If I am trying to display both of them my app is hanging.

The second question. Why Only `TextCell` works? I tried to use `Button` and `Label` and got exception on them.

Here is screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052746/xamarin-forms-binding-multiple-textcells-in-one-listview

Comment: You have to use a container view for your data template like `StackLayout` or `Grid`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use two cells in a single ListView.  You can use the TextCell's Detail property to display a 2nd line of text

```
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Age}" />
  </DataTemplate>
```

or you can create your own custom cell layout using ViewCell